# How to upgrade from VMware Workstation 6 to 10?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I have VMware Workstation 6 installed on Ubuntu 12.04, and I just downloaded the VMware Workstation 10 trial and I want to install it. What commands do I need to type in order to install it correctly?

Also for some reason (maybe it's that way because I only had VMware 6 until now) entering VMWARE command or `sudo vmware` command does not launch the program. I tried with every caps/notcaps/sudo/notsudo... but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do it, is by downloading the latest [VMWare](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation/10_0).

Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded(probably the Downloads folder), and run the command(s) below:

**For 32bit:**

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolbox gcc build-essential
sudo chmod +x ./VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
```

**For 64bit:**

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-dev open-vm-dkms open-vm-toolbox gcc build-essential
sudo chmod +x ./VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.x86_64.bundle
```

And just follow the installation screen to finish the install.

Comment: thank you Mitch!
silly quesiton here - im very VERY new to ubuntu (and linux) and just not sure why u need the ./ if im installing a file that is in the directory im in atm?

Comment: ./<filename> referrs to filename in current directory.